use lua script and redis for set pattern in location openresty
stream.conf.template:
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate     /ssl/ssl.everything;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl/ssl.key;

    server_name ${CDN_BASE_DOMAIN};

    location ~ ^/${MULTI_PATTERN_NAMES}/.*\.(ts|mp4|vtt|jpg|webp|webm) {
        log_by_lua_file /traffic.lua;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header X-App-Id streamer-nginx;
        add_header X-Server-Id ${CDN_SERVER_ID};
        rewrite ^/${MULTI_PATTERN_NAMES}/(.*)$ /$2 break;
        root ${VIDEOS_PATH};
    }

    location / {
        proxy_cache DISK_CACHE;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 10m;

        proxy_pass http://${CONTAINER_GO}:3000;
    }
}

.env file:
CONTAINER_GO=cdn-golang-app-container
CDN_BASE_DOMAIN=stream.sample.loc
VIDEOS_PATH=/storage
MULTI_PATTERN_NAMES=(serve-ts|sample-app|sample-pwa)

I have a Dockerized application that includes Golang, OpenResty, Redis, and Postgres services.
I had a problem before that was solved, which you can see in this link and finally added log_by_lua_file /traffic.lua; to stream.conf.template.
Now I want to do something else. I should use Lua Script instead of ${MULTI_PATTERN_NAMES} environment variable.
Suppose I have a variable in Redis named cdn_patterns=(serve-ts|sample-app|sample-pwa). Now I want to connect to redis in lua script and get this value from it. Then I want to create my pattern in Openresty using this value. Now I don't know what the solution is. Can I define a variable in Lua that can also be used in Openresty? Or is there another solution?
My reason for doing this is that I have a dashboard where the admin can add, remove or edit patterns. Before this, to add each pattern, I had to edit the .env file and then down and up the docker compose file once.
With this method, I am looking to dynamically define the patterns in the panel without the need to up and down the app
